# Ubuntu 14.04 can't detect wireless card

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on lenovo yoga 13. Previously my wireless was working correctly, but only after running a script to fix the wireless:

```
cd /opt/rtl8723au-master
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8723au
```

This no longer works though. I recently had an update for a new kernel version. After updating I can no longer use the above script to connect to wireless. The script now eventually returns: `Module 8723au not found`

iwconfig: `lo no wireless extensions`

lspci -vvnn | grep Network: `Nothing is returned`

uname -a: `Linux "computer-name" 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Also I would like to note this laptop does not have an ethernet port so I cannot connect to the internet at all.

If anyone has any suggestions that would be greatly appreciated, or if you need more info from me just let me know.

Comment: Please instead try: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: running lspci -nn | grep 0280 also resulted in no return values

Comment: We see no wireless device so far. How about: lspci -nn and also: lsusb. I wonder if your device has failed.

Comment: lsusb:
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b322 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2047:0855 Texas Instruments
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04f3:000a Elan Microelectronics Corp.
Bus 001 Device 005: ID obda:1724 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID obda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:02f4 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 2.4g Cordless Mouse

Comment: Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1b6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently. When the kernel gets update the headers for the driver also gets update. So we need the map the correct headers. I got a script similar to yours which worked for my driver.  You can try to change the driver (from rtl8188eu to rtl8723au) and check whether thats helps you. Run the code below in terminal and reboot.

Here is script what worked for my driver

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install git
sudo git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
cd rtl8188eu
sudo make all
sudo make install
sudo insmod 8188eu.ko
```

Comment: I ran the script up to the point of cloning the git repo. Since I do not have internet access I was unable to clone the repo. I don't have an ethernet port on my machine so that isn't an option unfortunately. Going to clone the repo on my other machine and copy it over, then I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: alright. I copied over the repo to my laptop. This was the result:
sudo make all:
make ARCH=x86 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/build M=/home/"user"/rtl8188eu modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make taget 'modules'. Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/build'
make: *** [modules] Error 2

Comment: sudo make install:
install -p -D -m 644 8188eu.ko /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/kerrnel/drivers/net/wireless/8188eu.ko
install: cannot stat '8188eu.ko': No such file or directory
make: *** [install] Error 1

sudo insmod 8188eu.ko:
insmod: ERROR: could not load module 8188eu.ko: No such file or directory

Comment: side note, is there a better way for me to comment. I couldn't get the comment to obey new lines. That looks way trashy. First time actually asking a question on here hehe

Comment: Guess you forgot to change the driver. Try to replace rtl8188eu by rtl8723au in the script and give a check.

Comment: oops, yeah sorry. I missed that. One sec

Comment: alright, I changed out for the driver. But still got the same result. It seems to me this line might be an issue: "make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'modules'. Stop." In the case of both drivers I got that error

Comment: check this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/318608/lenovo-yoga-13-realtek-wireless-driver

Comment: I'm still running into the same errors. 1. install: cannot stat '8723au.ko': No such file or directory 2. make[1] *** No rule to make target 'modules'. Stop. :\

Answer (score 0):

This is your wireless device:

> Bus 001 Device 005: ID obda:1724 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

It is covered by 8723au. I suggest you try:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au.git
cd rtl8723au
make
sudo make install
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe 8723au
```

When Update Manager installs a later kernel version, recompile after the required reboot:

```
cd ~/rtl8723au
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe 8723au
```

Comment: I copied the git repo on another computer and transferred it over with a usb (since I do not have internet access). Then I ran everything with no error up to the make command (line 4 of your answer): make ARCH=x86 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/build M=/home/"user"/rtl8188eu modules make[1]: Entering directory '/lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/build' make[1]: *** No rule to make taget 'modules'. Stop. make[1]: Leaving directory '/lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/build' make: *** [modules] Error 2

Comment: You are in the rtl8188eu directory. My answer was for rtl8723au.

Comment: sorry, I admittedly copy my comment from above since I am typing this out by hand without having access to the internet. I did actually run those commands using the rtl8723au directory. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: If you have no internet connection and therefore have no linux-headers-generic and no build-essential, the package will never compile. Downloading all those two packages and all of their dependencies will be a long, tedious process. If you install Ubuntu 14.10, the driver is included by default.

Comment: Alright, I was debating this already. Since it seemed that somehow my headers how gotten messed up/corrupted after updating the kernel (not sure how or why, I did it on the computer I'm currently on without a hitch). I will upgrade my version from 14.04 to 14.10 and let you know how it goes.