# I can't get my Lenovo Yoga 13 wifi driver to blacklist?

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers

I need to blacklist semi-useless wifi driver included with 14.04.2 and load stable one per these [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318608/lenovo-yoga-13-realtek-wireless-driver):

in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:

```
blacklist ideapad_laptop
blacklist rtl8723au
blacklist rtl8723ae
```

and then

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

reboot. Wifi still semi working and can't modprobe new driver (resource busy).

```
steve@steve-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Yoga-13:/etc/modprobe.d$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:1.4
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 2c:d0:5a:f6:f3:e0
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723au driverversion=3.16.0-31-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.6 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct driver to blacklist is `r8723au`.