# WiFi issues on a Lenovo Yoga 11s Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, realtek-wireless

I have been trying to figure out how to fix my Wi-Fi issues. I installed Ubuntu on this computer and was very happy that all was working out of the box. But after some time I realized there is a problem with my Wi-Fi connection.

The internet connection works fine for 5 minutes or less, but then it drops. I have to restart the Wi-Fi connection, it works fine for 5 minutes and same thing happens again, it drops.

I have read some people that had the same problem, or didn't have Wi-Fi connection at all like: [Installing Ubuntu Linux on a Lenovo Yoga 11s](http://sudomasochism.com/post/55464266362/installing-ubuntu-linux-on-a-lenovo-yoga-11s). I followed the steps, tried to change for Ubuntu 14.04, thinking that the problem would be solved on this new version, but it still remains on it.

Then I tried to ask here. My computer is a lenovo Yoga 11s, my OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, my Wi-Fi adapter is from Realtek.

The output of  `lspci -knn` on terminal:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3977]
    Kernel driver in use: ivb_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3977]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:0153] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3977]
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3977]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3977]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3977]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3977]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3977]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation QS77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e56] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3977]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3977]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3977]
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller [8086:1e24] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3977]
```

When I type `grep Net -A2` on terminal, nothing happens.

When I type l`spci -knn | grep Net -A2` nothing happens but the cursor turns back to the origin.

Here is the result of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 0bda:1724 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8723AU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 2047:0855 Texas Instruments Invensense Embedded MotionApp HID Sensor
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 03eb:8814 Atmel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Hello Pilot6,  I just have put the result of the terminal command. Thanks.

Comment: @EuclidesStolf `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` is a single command it should be typed togather

Comment: Is your adapter a USB dongle? Then add output of `lsusb`.

Comment: @Pilot6, I have  just edited the post with the informations. Thanks!

Comment: @Mohit Rajan, thanks, I am very new to all this.

Comment: @ Pilt6, I am not using a USB dongle. My internet comes down every time. But some times it stays stable for 5 minutes or so, it is when I can write to you. I tried to connect a USB dongle, but it didn't change the situation (or I didn't installed it correct). Thanks.

Comment: It looks like a hardware issue, like a bad contact. The internal wireless adapter is not sen at all.

Comment: @Pilot6 Eucides says he has connected to wifi so shouldn't the adapter be shown in `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: @MohitRajan Another option is that Yoga has a built in USB adapter. But it is not clear.

Comment: this is because the driver is unstable try this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/358479/511262

Answer (score 2):

I have found an answer in this website: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au/issues/52.

After istalling a drive for rtl8723au, wich I did following the instructions of the link in my question, I have blacklisted the native rtl8723au kernel module. I did:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe/blacklist.conf
```

then I writed in the blacklist text:

```
blacklist r8723au
```

Now my wifi is stable and my internet speed increased a lot.

Comment: Why do you write in comments that you are not using a USB dongle? This driver is for that dongle, not for the internal adapter.

Comment: This is not a very good way to install this driver. You will have to re-install it after each kernel upgrade. You can install `rtl8723au-dkms` package from Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what was a USB dongle.  I thought it was a external USB that could conect to Wi-fi. The driver I downloaded was the one from the link I first posted in my question, wich is for this internall: Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8723AU 802.11n WLAN Adapter.

Comment: OK. You have an internal USB adapter, that is not very common.

Comment: How can I install this 'rt18723au-dkms'  from Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: Oops. This one is not available, sry.