# No Wi-Fi adapter found on Lenovo Yoga L13, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lenovo, iwlwifi

I don't have an ethernet adapter.

If I go to **Settings > Wifi** there is "No Wi-Fi adapter Found".

```
lspci | grep Network
Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f0
```

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
Network controller[0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0030]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: First answer(updating kernel) of https://askubuntu.com/questions/784590/updated-wifi-fix-for-yoga-13-and-ubuntu-16-04 solved it.

Comment: But the problem is that `extended` branch in `rtlwifi-new` is empty now. The `rtw88` is in use.

Answer (score 0):

Using this linux kernel: `Linux 5.0.0-1052-oem-osp1` did it for me.

Comment: @OmarHossamAhmed This gives a solution (and is not merely commentary or a link to a solution somewhere else). So it is an answer. However, I recommend that you **[edit]** this to expand it with an explanation of how to use that kernel.