# Lenovo IdeaPad Yoga 13 Wireless

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo IdeaPad Yoga 13, and the computer is unable to connect to wifi.  No wireless networks appear in the connections menu.  I tried installing [This driver](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au) based off [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318608/lenovo-yoga-13-realtek-wireless-driver), but it didn't change anything.  I blacklisted the r8723au module from `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` to disable the previously installed driver, but the wireless still doesn't work.

EDIT:

`lspci | grep Wireless` and `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` both have no output, however the output of `lsusb` contains the wireless card:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:1724 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8723AU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

EDIT 2:

Output of `dmesg | grep 8723`:

```
[    4.906937] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723a_fw.bin  
[    5.129061] usb 1-1.4: RTL8723AU rev B (TSMC) 1T1R, TX queues 2, WiFi=1, BT=1, GPS=0, HI PA=0  
[    5.129064] usb 1-1.4: RTL8723AU MAC: 20:16:d8:b0:33:d7  
[    5.129068] usb 1-1.4: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723aufw_B_NoBT.bin  
[    5.731976] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8723au
```

EDIT 3:

Output of `rfkill list all`:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no 
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth     
Soft blocked: yes   
Hard blocked: no 
4: hci0: Bluetooth  
Soft blocked: no    
Hard blocked: no 
5: phy1: Wireless LAN   
Soft blocked: no    
Hard blocked: no
```

Output of `lsmod | grep 8723`:

`8723au                892928  0`

EDIT 4:

Full `lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
cmac                   16384  2
rtsx_usb_ms            20480  0
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         28672  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_usb_ms
rtsx_usb               24576  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
8723au                892928  0
rfcomm                 69632  2
arc4                   16384  2
bnep                   20480  2
rtl8xxxu               73728  0
mac80211              737280  1 rtl8xxxu
cfg80211              565248  1 mac80211
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             520192  29 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
hid_multitouch         20480  0
asix                   40960  0
usbnet                 45056  1 asix
mii                    16384  2 asix,usbnet
uvcvideo               90112  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
hid_sensor_magn_3d     16384  0
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
hid_sensor_accel_3d    16384  0
hid_sensor_gyro_3d     16384  0
hid_sensor_incl_3d     16384  0
hid_sensor_rotation    16384  0
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
hid_sensor_trigger     16384  10 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_magn_3d
industrialio_triggered_buffer    16384  5 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_magn_3d
hid_sensor_custom      20480  0
hid_sensor_iio_common    16384  6 hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_magn_3d
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
joydev                 20480  0
kvm                   536576  0
snd_hda_codec_conexant    24576  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
aesni_intel           167936  2
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
input_leds             16384  0
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
serio_raw              16384  0
snd                    81920  17 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mei_me                 36864  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
lpc_ich                24576  0
ideapad_laptop         24576  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
acpi_als               16384  0
kfifo_buf              16384  2 industrialio_triggered_buffer,acpi_als
industrialio           57344  9 hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,industrialio_triggered_buffer,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,acpi_als,hid_sensor_rotation,kfifo_buf,hid_sensor_magn_3d
int3400_thermal        16384  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
hid_sensor_hub         20480  8 hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_custom,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_iio_common
mac_hid                16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  3 hid_multitouch,hid_sensor_hub,usbhid
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
i915                 1208320  3
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        147456  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               126976  0
drm                   360448  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  3
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    20480  1 ideapad_laptop
video                  40960  2 i915,ideapad_laptop
fjes                   28672  0
```

`iwconfig`:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlx2016d8b033d7  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

enxac293adb851c  no wireless extensions.
```

EDIT 5:

`lsmod | grep 8723`:

```
r8723au               516096  0
cfg80211              565248  1 r8723au
```

`sudo modprobe 8723au`:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8723au': Device or resource busy
```

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci | grep Wireless` (CaSe SeNsiTivE)

Comment: I suggest the more informative `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

Comment: @AndroidDev I updated my question

Comment: @chili555 I updated my question.

Comment: What is the result of: `dmesg | grep 8723`?

Comment: @chili555 Updated.

Comment: Well now that's interesting. I wonder why the Wi-Fi card is on the USB bus?

Comment: May we also see: `rfkill list all` and: `lsmod | grep 8723` So far, we see nothing wrong and therefore fixable.

Comment: @chili555 Added output.

Comment: I wonder if the native driver is also loaded. Please post the following here: `lsmod` and `iwconfig` http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: @chili555 Added outputs.

Answer (score 1):

You have *both* the native driver rtl8xxxu and the compiled driver 8712au loaded. I suspect that they conflict. Until we find otherwise, I suspect that the native driver will work better. Let's blacklist 8723au:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist 8723au"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot.

Does the interface scan and see networks?

```
sudo iwlist scan
```

If it sees networks, it will probably connect.

Now that we know that this is ineffective, we will reverse the sequence and try the compiled driver only.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Change the last line, which now reads:

```
blacklist 8723au
```

To read:

```
blacklist rtl8xxxu
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Reboot.

Now does it scan?

From your paste, we see that there is a firmware issue. Let's try later firmware and see if it helps. With a temporary working internet connection:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
sudo modprobe -r r8723au && sudo modprobe r8723au
```

Also, your wireless card is in Monitor mode; it should be Managed:

```
sudo ifconfig wlx2016d8b033d7 down
sudo iwconfig wlx2016d8b033d7 mode managed
sudo ifconfig wlx2016d8b033d7 up
```

Also, be certain that in Network Manager, under WiFi, the mode is Client and not AdHoc.

Any improvement?

Comment: blacklisting 8723au didn't work.  `iwlist scan` gives 'No scan results'.  Should I try the same, but with "blacklist r8723au"?

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: I followed the instructions and the wireless option disappeared.  In the menubar, only wired connections appear, as well as in the 'Network' section of system settings.

Comment: Additionally, `sudo iwlist scan` shows `Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down`.

Comment: Is the correct driver loaded? `lsmod | grep 8723` If not, is there any message or warning if you load it? `sudo modprobe 8723au`

Comment: `lsmod` gave two results with 8723, and `modprobe` failed.  I added the outputs to the question.

Comment: Without changing anything, please run the wireless script as described here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180 paste the result here: http://paste.ubuntu.com  Then post the link here.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/21218745/

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb gave me a 404 error, so I used 1.159_all.deb instead.  Nothing seemed to change.  Network settings still has no wireless option, only Wired is showing up. I also ran the wireless script again: http://paste.ubuntu.com/21356660/

Answer (score 1):

I do not get any output from the command `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`, but I get an output from `sudo lspci -nnv |grep ualcom`, where ualcom is part of the name of my card. You need to substitute it with the name of your card.

I have a Lenovo i310, running Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.4).
The hardware has wi-fi, I use it on windows.
The wi-fi hardware is switched on.
However the wi-fi does not work, when I freshly start up the laptop.

The workaround for me is:

- switch on laptop
- press for a few seconds the power button
- switch on laptop again

Now wi-fi magically works.

The downside is that you need to do this operation every time you switch on laptop. Still looking for a permanent solution.

See also  [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761601/ubuntu-16-04-lenovo-thinkpad-sl500-wireless-driver-not-working/840619#840619)

Comment: well, the question is not exactly the same. not sure I can flag as duplicate.

Comment: I added some info